# Is there any NotNull annotation in dart?

Tags: dart, nullable, dart-null-safety

I have this little class:

```
class WidgetToImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(GlobalKey key)  builder;

  const WidgetToImage({Key? key, @required this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetToImageState createState() => _WidgetToImageState();
}
```

This chunk of code won't compile because anybody can pass a null value for the builder parameter when constructing the WidgetToImage widget. I know I could make the builder nullable but this is not what I want because later I must be checking if it is null, etc. and semantically it doesnt make any sense. A valid builder must be always passed.

Is there any way to annotate this in dart to avoid converting builder property to a nullable type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Dart version 2.12, you get null safety as a language feature.
It seems you are already using that since your code contains `Key?`, which is the null-safety way of writing "nullable".
On the other hand, your `this.builder` parameter should have been marked as `required` (a keyword in null safe code) instead of the older `@required` annotation, so it doesn't look like *valid* null safe code.

The code should read:

```dart
class WidgetToImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(GlobalKey key)  builder;

  const WidgetToImage({Key? key, required this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetToImageState createState() => _WidgetToImageState();
}
```

and then it's a compile-time error for null-safe code to pass `null` as an argument to `builder`.
(Older non-null-safe code can still get away with passing `null`, but they're asking for trouble then.)

You can add an assertion:

```dart
  const WidgetToImage({Key? key, required this.builder}) 
      : assert(builder as dynamic != null), 
        super(key: key);
```

that will tell people developing against your library to not pass in `null` from non-null-sound code, but only while developing with assertions enabled.

Comment: What I meant is if there was any "compile time" check. Instead of runtime. I know I can use assert but this is not what I expect from a modern typed language that has some really handy annotations. And for the required keyword, thanks for that. Did not notice they added that one.

Comment: @Notbad The point of the null-safety feature from Dart 2.12 is to add compile-time checks using the type system. See https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: @Notbad looking for the same "compile time" check any updates now?

Comment: Nop sorry. I ended up doing what Irn suggested. Not 100% happy though :)